# VBA - loop - copy all values starting with... (from two columns)

Tags: vba, for-loop

I have this code (loops through column and copy all values starting with "2020-") but:

```
Dim cell As Range
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("MATIKGL")  
Set ws2 = Sheets("2020") 

For Each cell In ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A65535").End(xlUp))
    If Left(cell, 5) = "2020-" Then
        ws2.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = cell
    End If
Next cell
```

But when value (starting with 2020-) is found I would like also to copy corresponding value right of column A from ws (column B) into ws2 (column b), without condition, just as it is.

I've tried with cell.resize but it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe `ws2.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = cell.offset(0,1)`?